# Springboot cassandra pagination

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, pagination

I'm trying to achieve pagination with cassandra but I'm not getting any successful solutions on Stackoverflow. The prominent error I'm getting is 'Paging queries for pages other than the first one require a CassandraPageRequest with a valid paging state'. Kindly assist.

Comment: please read this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/query/CassandraPageRequest.html

Comment: @AmmarAli Kindly share sample code or how i can implement it

Answer (score 4):

You must use the `CassandraPageRequest.of(pageIndex, resultsOnPage)`
Also to be able to use **findAll** query with page you must extends your repository interface with `CassandraRepositoy` to have the implementation for the query.

Example :

1. Declare a repository interface

```java
        @Repository
        public interface MyRepository extends CassandraRepository<MyModel, MapId>{

        }
```

2. Inject the repo and use the method findAll with pageable (you have to start with the page 0)

```java
           @Autowired
            private MyRepo repo;

            void someMethod(){
             int resultOnPage = ...
             //this is the first page
             Slice<MyModel> page= repository.findAll(CassandraPageRequest.of(0, resultOnPage ));
             // iterate the slice with iterator
             //.......

             //go ahead and take the next pages
             while (page.hasNext()) {
               page = repository.findAll(page.nextPageable());
               //process the page iterating it
             }
           }
```

Comment: This leads to the error : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create a Cassandra page request for an indexed page other than the first page (0). Any solution?

Comment: I forget to edit the answer... You must to start with the first page and then continue

Comment: what is `resultOnPage` here ?